# Compare two strings

Tags: c++

I have a function that is supossed to compare to strings:

```
int string_compare(char *str1, char *str2){
  while(*str1==*str2)
{
  if ( *str1 == '\0' || *str2 == '\0' )
     break;

  str1++;
  str2++;
}
 if( *str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0' )
  return 0;
else if(*str1 == '\0' && *str2 != '\0' )
  return -1;
 else 
   return 1;}
```

It shoud return 0 if those strings are identical , 1 if str1>str2 and -1 if str2

Edit: Now it shouldn't return any warning, but still it does not work correctly!

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem?

Comment: It does not handle (*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0')

Comment: sorry! the problem is that is not returning any of these values as if any of the ifs are validated.

Comment: @brianbeuning how should i write it then? That case will newver happen because of the first if

Comment: Add an `else` clause, where it returns the difference between the letters?

Comment: Why can't you just use `strcmp()`?

Comment: You might write a single char compare function first and get the insight that your solution (of the homework) is way to complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code given below to check whether the string is null.

```
   if (myString != NULL) {
      // doSomething
    }
```

And if you want to **compare two strings** try these:
   - `strcmp(string1, string2)==0`   if the CASE of string is also to be compared.
   - `strcmpi(string1,string2)==0`   if the CASE of string is **NOT** to be compared.

Comment: also you can use `myString[0] == '\0'`